# How can I link my program to another program?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program, Designed by C # and SQL Server databases
How can I import information from another program (Amadeus to book airline tickets) and displayed in DataGridView ???

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you explain more on 2nd system you tried to integrate

Comment: http://api.dev.amadeus.net/api/index.htm through API?

Comment: [Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+inter+program+communication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=c%23+interprocess+communication)

Comment: Please, improve your question. Here a few hints on how to do it: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either Web Api or SOAP services, please check this link it'll give you some information. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)
For Example there is an API: [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/)

**Update**: Basically your question is very general sort of way. I would suggest you to look for an booking flight API and read it's suggestion.

P.S accept the answer if it was any help.